# open folder by input in batch and C++ code

Tags: batch-file, shellexecute

I searched how to open the folder in batch code as following

```
%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe "c:\Yaya\yoyo\"
```

However, what if I want to give the specific folder everytime i execute the batch program?

If you don't mind, could you also please tell me how to do it in C++ as well?
It is hard to change the path by having scanf..

Currently I have

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
int main ()
 {
     HINSTANCE result;
     result=ShellExecute(NULL,NULL,L"c:\my_folder_path_by_input",NULL,NULL,SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
     if ((int)result<=32)
     std::cout << "Error!\nReturn value: " << (int)result << "\n";
     return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the batch file with path of folder to open as parameter and use in batch file `%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe "%~1"` or perhaps even better `%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe /e,"%~1"`.

Example:

Batch file `OpenFolder.bat` contains:

```
@echo off
if "%~1" == "" (
    %SystemRoot%\explorer.exe
) else (
    %SystemRoot%\explorer.exe /e,"%~1"
)
```

This batch file is started for example with one of the lines below:

```
OpenFolder.bat
OpenFolder.bat %windir%\Temp
OpenFolder.bat "%TEMP%"
OpenFolder.bat "%APPDATA%"
OpenFolder.bat "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop"
```

Enclosing the folder path in double quotes is always possible, but really required are the double quotes on running `OpenFolder` if the folder path contains anywhere a space character or one of these characters: `` &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~ ``

See also [Windows Explorer Command-Line Options](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/314853)

I'm not sure why a batch file is needed at all to open a specific folder in Windows Explorer. Pressing <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> opens in any Windows starting from Windows 95 a new Windows Explorer window. And entering in address bar of Explorer window one of the strings above results in displaying the appropriate folder. See also Microsoft page about [Windows Keyboard Shortcuts](http://www.microsoft.com/enable/products/keyboard.aspx).

Here is one more batch version asking user for a folder path if not specified as parameter on starting the batch file.

```
@echo off
if not "%~1" == "" (
    %SystemRoot%\explorer.exe /e,"%~1"
    goto :EOF
)

rem There is no folder path specified as parameter.
rem Prompt user for folder path and predefine the environment variable
rem with a double quote as value to avoid batch processing exit because of
rem a syntax error if the batch file user just hits key RETURN or ENTER.

set "FolderPath=""
set /P "FolderPath=Folder path: "

rem Remove all double quotes from string entered by the user.

set "FolderPath=%FolderPath:"=%"

if "%FolderPath%" == "" (
    %SystemRoot%\explorer.exe
) else (
    %SystemRoot%\explorer.exe /e,"%FolderPath%"
    set "FolderPath="
)
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?` ... explains `%~1` (first parameter without double quotes).
- `echo /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`

Comment: It has been decades but I would like to thank you for your suggestion and tutorials! Sorry my response was too late.

Comment: Thanks a lot again,